# Khan Academy: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, processing.js, khan-academy

I am programming a library that can transform polygons on Khan Academy, however I keep getting this error:

```
Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

with no line numbers.

My code:

```
var Point = function(x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

Point.prototype.rotate = function(around,degrees) {
    angleMode = "degrees";
    var aX = around.x;
    var aY = around.y;
    var cX = this.x;
    var cY = this.y;
    var dist = sqrt(sq(cX-aX)+sq(cY-aY));
    var currentTheta = asin(dist/cY);
    var gamma = degrees+currentTheta;
    this.x = cos(gamma)*dist+aX;
    this.y = sin(gamma)*dist+aY;
};

var Line = function(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
    this.f = new Point(x1,y1);
    this.s = new Point(x2,y2);
};

Line.prototype.draw = function() {
    line(this.f.x,this.f.y,this.s.x,this.s.y);
};

Line.prototype.rotate = function(around,degrees) {
    this.f = this.f.rotate(around,degrees);
    this.s = this.s.rotate(around,degrees);
};

var Polygon = function(x,y){
    if(x.length!==y.length){return;}
    this.sides = x.length;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.lines = new Array(this.sides);
    this.lines[0] = new Line(this.x[this.sides-1],this.y[this.sides-1],this.x[0],this.y[0]);
    for(var i=1;i<this.sides;i++){
        this.lines[i] = new Line(this.x[i-1],this.y[i-1]);
    }
};

Polygon.prototype.draw = function() {
    for(var i=0;i<this.sides;i++){
        this.lines[i].draw();
    }
};

Polygon.prototype.rotate = function(around,degrees) {
    for(var i=0;i<this.sides;i++){
        this.lines[i].rotate(around,degrees);
    }
};

var p = new Polygon([10,20,40],[40,20,15]);

var draw = function() {
    background(255,255,255);
    fill(0,0,0);
    stroke(0,0,0);
    p.rotate(new Point(20,20),1);
    p.draw();
};
```

I however still do not know why it throws the error, especially because it gives no direction to where the error is. 


## EDIT


Link to project: [Transformation Library](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/transformation-library/4810101904441344)

Comment: That code alone doesn't give such an error, is there anything else?

Comment: @JaromandaX These functions are default in khanacademy, fill and stroke are for drawing.

Comment: EDIT: added link to project @JaromandaX

Comment: @JaromandaX Please notice the [tag:processing.js] and [tag:khan-academy] tags. This isn't a vanilla JavaScript question, so your questions don't make a ton of sense. Also Khan Academy disables `console.log()`.

Comment: @JaromandaX Not on Khan Academy, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with your `Point` class and its `rotate()` function:

```
Point.prototype.rotate = function(around,degrees) {
    angleMode = "degrees";
    var aX = around.x;
    var aY = around.y;
    var cX = this.x;
    var cY = this.y;
    var dist = sqrt(sq(cX-aX)+sq(cY-aY));
    var currentTheta = asin(dist/cY);
    var gamma = degrees+currentTheta;
    this.x = cos(gamma)*dist+aX;
    this.y = sin(gamma)*dist+aY;
};
```

This function does some math and sets the `this.x` and `this.y` variables. So far so good (disclaimer: I haven't checked this math, but that's not the point). But notice that **this function doesn't return anything.**

Now let's go to your `Line` class and its `rotate()` function:

```
Line.prototype.rotate = function(around,degrees) {  
   this.f = this.f.rotate(around,degrees);
   this.s = this.s.rotate(around,degrees);
};
```

This sets the `f` and `s` variables to the value returned from the `rotate()` function. But wait, the `rotate()` function in the `Point` class doesn't return anything! So now `this.f` and `this.s` are **undefined**!

You have a similar problem with your `Polygon` class calling the `Line` class's `rotate()` function.

So to fix your problem, you either need the `rotate()` functions to return something, or you need to just call them instead of expecting a return value.

Taking a step back, I wonder why you're doing all of this yourself. Processing has its own `rotate()` functions that do all of this for you. Why don't you just use them instead?

Comment: Thanks! I missed that...
I'm writing this myself because it is a project.

Comment: @EricHe if this solves your problem, you might want to mark this as an answer